# Program execute timer showing 0.000 seconds all the time

Tags: testing, time

so i have this counting sort code and i need to test how fast does it work for certain number of numbers. 10,1000,5000,10000 etc. now i have a problem,i found some code for execution time in C and it shows no errors,but whenever i start it i always have same result. 0.000000 seconds or milliseconds even nanoseconds.
so this is my code:

```
void CountingSort(int array[], int k, int n,int min)
{

   int i, j;
int B[50000], C[100000];
for (i = 0; i <= k+min; i++){
 C[i] = 0;
}
for (j = 0; j < n; j++){
 C[array[j]+min]++;
}
for (i = 1; i <= k+min; i++){
 C[i] += C[i-1];
}
for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
  B[--C[array[j]+min]] = array[j];
}
printf("Counting sort: \n");
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
   printf("%d ", B[i]);
}
printf("\n");
}

void minimum(int array[],int *min,int n){
int i;
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
    if (array[i] < *min) {
        *min= array[i];
                      }
    }
} 

void max(int array[],int *k,int n){
int i;
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (array[i] > *k) {
        *k = array[i];
                      }
    }
}

int main(int brArg,char *arg[])
{


int array[1000000];
int i=0,j,k=0,n,x,z,min=0,prsk=0;

 printf("Ten random numbers in [1,100]\n");

  for (i = 0; i < 5000; i++) {
n = rand() % 200 + 1;
printf("I[%d]=%d\n",i, n);
array[i]=n;
printf("arr %d \n",array[i]);
  }



n=i;
max(array,&k,n);
minimum(array,&min,n);
min=abs(min);

clock_t t;
double time_spent;

t = clock();

CountingSort(array,k,n,min);

t = clock() - t;
double time_taken = ((double)t)/(CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000000000.0); // in seconds

printf("counting took %f miliseconds to execute \n", time_taken); 

return 0;

}
```

now you dont have to look at the code how it works or anything it works fine i only need help for that time testing at the end,what i did wrong so time test doesent work?

Comment: why not have a start time as datetime and end time as datetime. At the end of your code have a timespan that gets the difference between the two....

Comment: i tried that way too,but again it shows 0.00000 seconds

Comment: I run your code on my computer, it returns: counting took 1003000.000000 miliseconds to execute

Comment: oh my God... if this is problem with my version of linux i will cry xD... thank you man! thanks for your help!

Comment: I don't think so! I'm suspecting it should be some more subtle bug

Comment: i am testing it now it shows 1000000.000 for 1000 nubmers and for 12000... so something is wrong... do you think maybe execute time doesent work for sorting codes?